# I cannot enable Youtube Analytics API at Google Developers Console

Tags: youtube-analytics-api

I was following the guidelines by Google to use Youtube Analytics API.

I have created credentials as written and tried to enable Youtube Analytics API, but I keep getting the following error message:

The API "youtubeanalytics.googleapis.com" doesn't exist or you don't have permission to access it

I thought it was very odd because I can enable every other APIs except this one, so anyone can help?

Thank you!

edit: I deleted the screenshot.

Comment: Looks same at my project, I suggest that you might need to open an issue at https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Defect%20Report) to report this issue to the appropriate team...

Comment: I just created an issue at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37115473, and you can star the issue there to get further updates from the YouTube team, thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I starred your report.

Comment: Great, and I will post this as an answer so that further questions regarding this can be properly route to the issue tracker there -:p

Answer (score 2):

I can easily reproduce this, so I've created an open issue as [#37115473](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37115473), and anyone having the same issue can star the issue there to get further updates from the YouTube team, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have the same eeror! I see many feedback about the same error in the ticket created by @JL-HN. Let's hope Google will fix it soon.